# Laravel 5.6 Hash

Tags: laravel, hash, passwords, sha

I know the question was already ask but i have tried without success.

We have an old database with SHA256 and double salt and we wan't to use this for Register and Login.

I have follow this tutorial and many more : https://conceptsandimplementation.wordpress.com/2017/03/07/replace-laravels-default-password-hash-bcrypt-with-base64-encode/

This my code :

```
namespace App\Libs\CustomHash;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher as HasherContract;

class CustomHasher implements HasherContract {

    public function info($hashedValue) {

    }

    /**
     * Hash the given value.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return array   $options
     * @return string
     */
    public function make($value, array $options = array()) {
        $PasswordHashed = 'a5df5z' . $value . 'a45ee1a';
        $PasswordHashed = hash('sha256', $value);
        return $PasswordHashed;
    }

    /**
     * Check the given plain value against a hash.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @param  string  $hashedValue
     * @param  array   $options
     * @return bool
     */
    public function check($value, $hashedValue, array $options = array()) {
        return $this->make($value) === $hashedValue;
    }

    /**
     * Check if the given hash has been hashed using the given options.
     *
     * @param  string  $hashedValue
     * @param  array   $options
     * @return bool
     */
    public function needsRehash($hashedValue, array $options = array()) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

And :

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider;
use App\Libs\CustomHash\CustomHasher as CustomHasher;

class CustomHashServiceProvider extends HashServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('hash', function () {
            return new CustomHasher;
        });
    }
}
```

Here my providers list

```
//Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\CustomHashServiceProvider::class,
```

I know that's not a good practive to use SHA but i do not have the choice.

Thank's in advance for you're help.

Comment: What is your question here? Does something not working?

Comment: So... What is the question?

Comment: Sorry, when i use this code the password are encrypted with bcrypt. Laravel doens't want to use my new HashServiceProvider.

Comment: Have you tried app('hash') to see what it returns?  SHA256 is fine, the insecure part of your code is the salt.

Comment: How to use app('hash') please ? I have check in the documentation but it's not indicate https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/hashing